# How to use top or htop to gather filtered time series

Tags: top, htop

My goal is to track the resource usage of a certain command in a easily parse-able time-series. Here's an example where I'm tracking all the `node` commands for 3 batches:

```
top -b -n3 | grep node                
 222097 root      20   0  954444 672616  32452 S 105.9   4.1  46:23.02 node
 221922 root      20   0  305792  51408  23900 S   0.0   0.3   0:00.58 node
 222113 root      20   0  554304 343092  23736 S   0.0   2.1   0:26.25 node
 222097 root      20   0  954444 672616  32452 S 159.8   4.1  46:27.83 node
 221922 root      20   0  305792  51408  23900 S   0.0   0.3   0:00.58 node
 222113 root      20   0  554304 343092  23736 S   0.0   2.1   0:26.25 node
 222097 root      20   0  954444 672616  32452 S 167.1   4.1  46:32.86 node
 221922 root      20   0  305792  51408  23900 S   0.0   0.3   0:00.58 node
 222113 root      20   0  554304 343092  23736 S   0.0   2.1   0:26.25 node
```

The problem is that there's no easy way to distinguish between batches. In this simple example it's easy to see the break point, but in a longer series, or one with more processes it becomes difficult.

With some heavy scripting we could do something fancy, but I'd like to keep it simple. Hoped for output:

```
 221922 root      20   0  305792  51408  23900 S   0.0   0.3   0:00.58 node
 222113 root      20   0  554304 343092  23736 S   0.0   2.1   0:26.25 node
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 222097 root      20   0  954444 672616  32452 S 159.8   4.1  46:27.83 node
 221922 root      20   0  305792  51408  23900 S   0.0   0.3   0:00.58 node
 222113 root      20   0  554304 343092  23736 S   0.0   2.1   0:26.25 node
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 222097 root      20   0  954444 672616  32452 S 167.1   4.1  46:32.86 node
 221922 root      20   0  305792  51408  23900 S   0.0   0.3   0:00.58 node
 222113 root      20   0  554304 343092  23736 S   0.0   2.1   0:26.25 node
```

Answer (score 1):

This imperfect bash script took me less time than writing this post:

```bsh
# /bin/bash

echo "Monitor process $1"
echo " for $2 batches"


for i in $(seq 1 $2); do 
    top -b -n 1 | grep $1
    echo "-------------------------------------------------";
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: While this does do what it says on the label, prints out the filtered processes, it's showing the MEM consumption in percentages, which doesn't really fit my desired use-case of showing memory consumed. I understand "memory consumed" is a vague statement, but I'd like some heuristic to compare two different configurations.